# How to run php encryption function on javascript files?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to redirect the page when the ajax function is successful. But the link parameters that I want to redirect will be encrypted with php encryption function. 
I write my code like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url('sistem/check'); ?>',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {   
           code: code,
           id: id
          },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             console.log(textStatus + ": " + jqXHR.status);
             console.log(data);
             var y = JSON.parse(data);
             var x = y.data.id;
             console.log(y.data.id)
             if (y.status !== 0){
                window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url('sistem/detail/'.encryption('x').''); ?>";
             }else{
             $('.response').html(y.message);
             }
             },
     error:(e) =>{
                    console.log(e.responseText);
                 }
           });
```

but writing like this makes php encrypt the string x not the variable x. 
Meanwhile, if I remove the quotes it makes this code an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript is running in the browser, you can't pass the JavaScript variable to PHP for encryption, because PHP runs on the server. In your PHP code, create an encrypted version of the data id and send it back to the client.

For example (in PHP):

```
$data->encryptedId = encrypted($data->id);
```

And you could update your JavaScript like so:

```
window.location.href = "sistem/detail/" + y.data.encryptedId;
```

*This approach to encryption isn't secure. You could send only the encrypted id from the server to client and/or use HTTPS, but even then, if anyone gets the URL, the data is accessible.*